# How to associate a commit to a branch

Tags: git

I have started fiddling with Git using [this](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) reference and I created some `commit object`s with `commit-tree`.

The problem is that when I execute `git log`, I get the following error:

```
fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet
```

I think that `commit-tree` doesn't create and association between the `commit` object and the current branch.

Is there a way to make this association using `commit-tree`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to make this association using `commit-tree`?

No, and that's the whole *point* of [`git commit-tree`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit-tree.html): it's what Git calls a *plumbing* command, that implements just some small part of the whole system.  It does one piece of the whole job, the way a valve or pipe or drain or shower-head does just one *piece* of the job.  You need more pieces to assemble a complete shower.

The plumbing piece that updates references (including branch names, but also other references as well) is [`git update-ref`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-ref.html).

(Note that to have a tree you can attach to a commit, you also need [`git write-tree`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-write-tree.html), which in turn needs you to create and populate the index, e.g., using [`git update-index`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html).  This is all covered in the Git internals page you linked to, but they did leave out the last step with `git update-ref`.)

If you want to create commits and put them on branches in the usual way, you should use the *porcelain commands* like `git add` and `git commit`.  These are intended to be human-friendly (how well they achieve this particular goal is a [matter of opinion](https://git-man-page-generator.lokaltog.net/) :-) ).